# Attempting to implement a second texture in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, texture-mapping

So i have created this scene but i am unsure how to implement a different texture to another object i have created. the scene rendered:

[image: img].

Currently in rending the scene I get both objects and i don't have the second object (table) showing a texture. It would be easy to implement the same texture but what I am looking to do is add a different texture to the table. I attempted to do the following the attempt to adjust function:

[image: img]

but was met with a black screen. Although i think this attempt may have been the correct step in the right direction (i could be wrong) i am unsure how to attach the texture to the Vertices array. I have the original code below (removed the mouse functionality due the to post limit of characters). Apologize in advance I had to remove some code to get the question to post. Light source shaders etc.

```
    `#include <iostream>`

    #include <GL/glew.h>
    #include <GL/freeglut.h>

    #include <glm/glm.hpp>
    #include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
    #include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

    //SOIL image loader inclusion
    #include "SOIL2/SOIL2.h"

using namespace std;

#define WINDOW_TITLE "ms 330"

#ifndef GLSL
#define GLSL(Version, Source) "#version " #Version "\n" #Source
#endif

GLint shaderProgram, WindowWidth = 800, WindowHeight = 600;
GLuint VBO, VAO, EBO, texture;
GLfloat degrees = glm::radians(0.0f);

GLfloat cameraRotation = glm::radians(-45.0f);
GLfloat cameraSpeed = 0.0005f; // movement speed per frame
GLchar currentKey; //will store key pressed


//Cube and light color
glm::vec3 lightColor(0.78f, 0.88f, 1.0f); //applied overcast sky like  201,226,255 rbg values equal
glm::vec3 secondLightColor(0.49f, 0.43f, 0.40f); //applied light brown to second color

//Light position and scale
glm::vec3 lightPosition(-1.0f, 2.0f, -3.0f);
glm::vec3 lightScale(0.3f);    
glm::vec3 lightStrength(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.25f);//ambient   specular    highlight

//set scale by axis numbers
GLfloat scale_by_y = 1.0f;
GLfloat scale_by_x = 1.0f;
GLfloat scale_by_z = 1.0f;

GLfloat lastMouseX = 400, lastMouseY = 300; // Locks mouse cursor at center of screen
GLfloat mouseXOffset, mouseYOffset, yaw = 0.0f, pitch = 0.0f, zoom = 0.0f; // mouse offset, yaw, and pitch variables
GLfloat sensitivity = 0.005f; // used for mouse/camera rotation sensitivity

//vstate for view state set at perspective intially
int vstate = 1;
//for keymod for glutmodifers
int keymod;

bool checkMotion = false;
bool leftMouseButton = false;
bool rightMouseButton = false;
bool altDown = false;

//Global vector declarations
glm::vec3 cameraPosition = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f); // initial camera position placed 5 units in z
glm::vec3 CameraUpY = glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // temporary y unit vector
glm::vec3 CameraForwardZ = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f); // temporary z unit vector
glm::vec3 front; // temporary z unit vector for mouse
glm::vec3 cameraRotateAmt;

void UResizeWindow(int,int);
void URenderGraphics(void);
void UCreateShader(void);
void UCreateBuffers(void);
void UMouseMove(int x, int y);
void UMouseClick(int button, int state, int x, int y);
void UGenerateTexture(void);
void UKeyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y);
void UKeyReleased(unsigned char key, int x, int y);

//VERTEX SHADER SOURCE CODE
const GLchar * vertexShaderSource = GLSL(330,
    layout (location = 0) in vec3 position; //vertex data from vertex attrib pointer 0
    layout (location = 2) in vec2 textureCoordinate;

    out vec2 mobileTextureCoordinate;

    //global variables for the transform matrices
    uniform mat4 model;
    uniform mat4 view;
    uniform mat4 projection;

    void main(){
        gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(position, 1.0f); //transforms vertices to clip coordinates
        mobileTextureCoordinate = vec2(textureCoordinate.x, 1.0f - textureCoordinate.y); //flips the texture horizontal
    }
);

//FRAGMENT SHADER SOURCE CODE
const GLchar * fragmentShaderSource = GLSL(330,
    in vec2 mobileTextureCoordinate;

    out vec4 gpuTexture; //variable to pass color data to the GPU

    uniform sampler2D uTexture; //Useful when working with multiple textures

    void main(){
        gpuTexture = texture(uTexture, mobileTextureCoordinate);
    }
);

//LIGHT VERTEX SHADER CODE
const GLchar * lightVertexShaderSource = GLSL(330,
    layout (location = 0) in vec3 position; //VAP position 0 for vertex position data
    layout (location = 1) in vec3 normal; //VAP position 1 for normals
    layout (location = 2) in vec2 textureCoordinate;

    out vec3 Normal; //for outgoing normals to fragment shader
    out vec3 FragmentPos; // for outgoing color / pixels to fragment shader
    out vec2 mobileTextureCoordinate; // uv coords for texture

    //uniform / global variables for the transform matrices
    uniform mat4 model;
    uniform mat4 view;
    uniform mat4 projection;

    void main(){
        gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(position, 1.0f);//Transforms vertices into clip coordinates
        Normal = mat3(transpose(inverse(model))) * normal; // get normal vectors in world space only and exclude normal translation properties
        FragmentPos = vec3(model * vec4(position, 1.0f)); //Gets fragment / pixel position in world space only (exclude view and projection)
        mobileTextureCoordinate = vec2(textureCoordinate.x, 1.0f - textureCoordinate.y); //flips the texture horizontal
    }
);

//MAIN PROGRAM
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowSize(WindowWidth, WindowHeight);
    glutCreateWindow(WINDOW_TITLE);

    glutReshapeFunc(UResizeWindow);

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
        if(glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
            std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLEW" << std:: endl;
            return -1;
        }

    UCreateShader();

    UCreateBuffers(); // Call Buffer function

    UGenerateTexture();

    glUseProgram(shaderProgram); //Use Shader Program

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // Set background color

    glutDisplayFunc(URenderGraphics);





    glutMainLoop();

    //Destroy Buffer objects once used
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1,&VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &EBO);

    return 0;
}

/*Resize window*/
void UResizeWindow(int w, int h) {
    WindowWidth = w;
    WindowHeight = h;
    glViewport(0, 0, WindowWidth, WindowHeight);
}

/*Renders graphics*/
void URenderGraphics(void) {

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); // enable z-depth

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // clears the screen

    glBindVertexArray(VAO); // Activate vertex array object before rendering and transforming them

    //Transform object
    glm::mat4 model;
    model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(6.0f, 6.0f, 6.0f)); //Increase the object size by a scale of 6
    model = glm::rotate(model, degrees, glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0f, 0.0f)); //Rotate the object y -45 degrees
    model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0f, 0.0f)); //Place the object at the center of the viewport
    model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(scale_by_x,scale_by_y,scale_by_z)); // Increase scale of object by scale of xyz

    //transform camera
    glm::mat4 view;
    view = glm::lookAt(cameraPosition, CameraForwardZ, CameraUpY);
    view = glm::rotate(view, cameraRotateAmt.x, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
    view = glm::rotate(view, cameraRotateAmt.y, glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));

    //transform projection
    glm::mat4 projection;

    if(vstate == 1){
        projection = glm::perspective(45.0f, (GLfloat)WindowWidth / (GLfloat)WindowHeight, 0.1f, 100.0f);

    }else if(vstate == 0){
        projection = glm::ortho(-5.0f, 5.0f, -5.0f, 5.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
    }


    //Retrieves and passes transform matrices to the shader program
    GLint modelLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "model");
    GLint viewLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "view");
    GLint projectionLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "projection");
    GLint secondLightColorLoc, lightColorLoc, lightPositionLoc, lightStrengthLoc, viewPositionLoc;

    glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(projectionLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));

    lightColorLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "lightColor");
    lightPositionLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "lightPos");
    lightStrengthLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "lightStrength");
    secondLightColorLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "secondLightColor");
    viewPositionLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "viewPosition");

    //pass color, light, and camera data to the cube shader programs corresponding uniforms
    glUniform3f(lightColorLoc, lightColor.r, lightColor.g, lightColor.b);
    glUniform3f(secondLightColorLoc, secondLightColor.r, secondLightColor.g, secondLightColor.b);
    glUniform3f(lightPositionLoc, lightPosition.x, lightPosition.y, lightPosition.z);
    glUniform3f(lightStrengthLoc, lightStrength.x, lightStrength.y, lightStrength.z);
    glUniform3f(viewPositionLoc, cameraPosition.x, cameraPosition.y, cameraPosition.z);

    glutPostRedisplay();

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 1000, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0); //Draw triangles

    glBindVertexArray(0); // Deactivate vertex array object

    glutSwapBuffers(); // Flips back buffer with front buffer every frame
}

//CREATE SHADER PROGRAMS
void UCreateShader() {
    //Vertex Shader
    GLint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER); // create vertex shader
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &lightVertexShaderSource, NULL); // attach vertex shader to source code
    glCompileShader(vertexShader); // compile vertex shader

    //Fragment Shader
    GLint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER); // create fragment shader
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &lightFragmentShaderSource, NULL); // attach fragment shader to source code
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader); // compile fragment shader

    //Shader program
    shaderProgram = glCreateProgram(); // create shader program and return ID
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader); // attach vertex shader to program
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader); // attach fragment shader to program
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram); // link vertex and fragment shaders to program

    //Delete vertex and fragment shaders once linked
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
}

//CREAT BUFFERS AND OBJECTS
void UCreateBuffers() {
    //Position and color data
    GLfloat vertices[] = {
            //X   //Y   //Z         //NORMALS           //TEXTURE COOR

            //chair leg one
            0.6f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,   1.0f,  0.0f,    //0
            0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,   0.75f, 0.0f,    //1
            0.6f, -1.0f, -0.1f,  0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,   0.0f,  0.0f,    //2
            0.5f, -1.0f, -0.1f,  0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,   0.5f,  0.0f,    //3

            0.6f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,   1.0f,  1.0f,    //4
            0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,   0.75f, 1.0f,    //5
            0.6f,  0.0f, -0.1f,  0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,   0.0f,  1.0f,    //6
            0.5f,  0.0f, -0.1f,  0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,   0.5f,  1.0f,    //7

            //chair leg two
            -0.6f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,  1.0f, 0.0f,     //8
            -0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,  0.75f,0.0f,     //9
            -0.6f, -1.0f, -0.1f,  0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,  0.0f, 0.0f,     //10
            -0.5f, -1.0f, -0.1f,  0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,  0.5f, 0.0f,     //11

            -0.6f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,  1.0f, 1.0f,     //12
            -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,  0.75f,1.0f,     //13
            -0.6f,  0.0f, -0.1f,  0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,  0.0f, 1.0f,     //14
            -0.5f,  0.0f, -0.1f,  0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,  0.5f, 1.0f,     //15

            //chair leg three
            0.6f, -1.0f, -0.9f,  0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,   1.0f, 0.0f,     //16
            0.5f, -1.0f, -0.9f,  0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,   0.75f,0.0f,     //17
            0.6f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,   0.0f, 0.0f,     //18
            0.5f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,   0.5f, 0.0f,     //19

            0.6f,  0.0f, -0.9f,   0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,  1.0f, 1.0f,     //20
            0.5f,  0.0f, -0.9f,   0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,  0.75f,1.0f,     //21
            0.6f,  0.0f, -1.0f,   0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,  0.0f, 1.0f,     //22
            0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,   0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,  0.5f, 1.0f,     //23

            //chair leg four
            -0.6f, -1.0f, -0.9f,  0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,  1.0f, 0.0f,     //24
            -0.5f, -1.0f, -0.9f,  0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,  0.75f,0.0f,     //25
            -0.6f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,  0.0f, 0.0f,     //26
            -0.5f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,  0.5f, 0.0f,     //27

            -0.6f,  0.0f, -0.9f,  0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,  1.0f, 1.0f,     //28
            -0.5f,  0.0f, -0.9f,  0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,  0.75f,1.0f,     //29
            -0.6f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,  0.0f, 1.0f,     //30
            -0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,  0.5f, 1.0f,     //31

            //seat cushion
             0.7f, 0.1f,  0.0f,   0.9f, 0.9f, 0.8f,     0.0f, 0.0f,     //32 //ATTEMPTED TO LEAVE  TEXTURE OFF CUSHION BUT STILL GOT texture O.0f
            -0.7f, 0.1f,  0.0f,   0.9f, 0.9f, 0.8f,     0.0f, 0.0f,     //33
             0.7f, 0.2f,  0.0f,   0.9f, 0.9f, 0.8f,     0.0f, 0.0f,     //34
            -0.7f, 0.2f,  0.0f,   0.9f, 0.9f, 0.8f,     0.0f, 0.0f,     //35

             0.6f, 0.1f, -0.9f,   0.9f, 0.9f, 0.8f,     0.0f, 0.0f,     //36
             0.6f, 0.2f, -0.9f,   0.9f, 0.9f, 0.8f,     0.0f, 0.0f,     //37

            -0.6f, 0.1f, -0.9f,   0.9f, 0.9f, 0.8f,     0.0f, 0.0f,     //38
            -0.6f, 0.2f, -0.9f,   0.9f, 0.9f, 0.8f,     0.0f, 0.0f,     //39

            //chair base
             0.6f, 0.0f,  0.0f,   0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,  0.0f, 0.0f,     //40
            -0.6f, 0.0f,  0.0f,   0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,  1.0f, 0.0f,     //41
             0.6f, 0.1f,  0.0f,   0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,  0.25f, 0.0f,    //42
            -0.6f, 0.1f,  0.0f,   0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,  1.0f, 0.25f,    //43

             0.6f, 0.0f, -1.0f,   0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,  0.0f, 0.25f,    //44
             0.6f, 0.1f, -1.0f,   0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,  0.0f, 0.25f,    //45

            -0.6f, 0.0f, -1.0f,   0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,  1.0f, 0.25f,    //46
            -0.6f, 0.1f, -1.0f,   0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,  1.0f, 0.25f,    //47


            //chair back tower 1
            0.5f, 0.1f, -0.9f,  0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,    1.0f, 0.0f,     //48
            0.6f, 0.1f, -0.9f,  0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,    0.75f,0.0f,     //49
            0.5f, 0.1f, -1.0f,  0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,    0.0f, 0.0f,     //50
            0.6f, 0.1f, -1.0f,  0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,    0.5f, 0.0f,     //51

            0.5f, 1.2f, -1.1f,  0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,    1.0f, 1.0f,     //52
            0.6f, 1.2f, -1.1f,  0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,    0.75f,1.0f,     //53
            0.5f, 1.2f, -1.2f,  0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,    0.0f, 1.0f,     //54
            0.6f, 1.2f, -1.2f,  0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,    0.5f, 1.0f,     //55

            //chair back tower 2
           -0.5f, 0.1f, -0.9f,  0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,    1.0f, 0.0f,     //56
           -0.6f, 0.1f, -0.9f,  0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,    0.75f,0.0f,     //57
           -0.5f, 0.1f, -1.0f,  0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,    0.0f, 0.0f,     //58
           -0.6f, 0.1f, -1.0f,  0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,    0.5f, 0.0f,     //59

           -0.5f, 1.2f, -1.1f,  0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,    1.0f, 1.0f,     //60
           -0.6f, 1.2f, -1.1f,  0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,    0.75f, 1.0f,    //61
           -0.5f, 1.2f, -1.2f,  0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,    0.0f, 1.0f,     //62
           -0.6f, 1.2f, -1.2f,  0.17f, 0.11f, 0.05f,    0.5f, 1.0f,     //63

           //chair horiz back top
            0.5f, 1.1f, -1.1f,  0.39f, 0.26f, 0.12f,    0.0f, 0.0f,     //64
           -0.5f, 1.1f, -1.1f,  0.39f, 0.26f, 0.12f,    1.0f, 0.0f,     //65
           -0.5f, 1.2f, -1.1f,  0.39f, 0.26f, 0.12f,    1.0f, 0.5f,     //66
            0.5f, 1.2f, -1.1f,  0.39f, 0.26f, 0.12f,    0.0f, 0.5f,     //67

            0.5f, 1.1f, -1.2f,  0.39f, 0.26f, 0.12f,    0.0f, 0.0f,     //68
           -0.5f, 1.1f, -1.2f,  0.39f, 0.26f, 0.12f,    1.0f, 0.0f,     //69
           -0.5f, 1.2f, -1.2f,  0.39f, 0.26f, 0.12f,    1.0f, 0.5f,     //70
            0.5f, 1.2f, -1.2f,  0.39f, 0.26f, 0.12f,    0.0f, 0.5f,     //71

            //chair horiz back bottom
            0.5f, 0.4f, -1.0f,  0.39f, 0.26f, 0.12f,    0.0f, 0.0f,     //72
           -0.5f, 0.4f, -1.0f,  0.39f, 0.26f, 0.12f,    1.0f, 0.0f,     //73
           -0.5f, 0.5f, -1.0f,  0.39f, 0.26f, 0.12f,    1.0f, 0.5f,     //74
            0.5f, 0.5f, -1.0f,  0.39f, 0.26f, 0.12f,    0.0f, 0.5f,     //75

            0.5f, 0.4f, -1.05f,  0.39f, 0.26f, 0.12f,   0.0f, 0.0f,     //76
           -0.5f, 0.5f, -1.05f,  0.39f, 0.26f, 0.12f,   1.0f, 0.0f,     //77
           -0.5f, 0.4f, -1.05f,  0.39f, 0.26f, 0.12f,   1.0f, 0.5f,     //78
            0.5f, 0.5f, -1.05f,  0.39f, 0.26f, 0.12f,   0.0f, 0.5f,     //79

            //chair rung 1 front to back

            0.58f, -0.4f, -0.10f, 0.39f, 0.26f, 0.12f,  0.0f, 0.25f,    //80
            0.55f, -0.4f, -0.10f, 0.39f, 0.26f, 0.12f,  0.0f, 0.5f,     //81
            0.55f, -0.5f, -0.10f, 0.39f, 0.26f, 0.12f,  0.0f, 0.75f,    //82
            0.58f, -0.5f, -0.10f, 0.39f, 0.26f, 0.12f,  0.0f, 0.0f,     //83

            0.58f, -0.4f, -0.90f, 0.39f, 0.26f, 0.12f,  1.0f, 0.25f,    //84
            0.55f, -0.4f, -0.90f, 0.39f, 0.26f, 0.12f,  1.0f, 0.5f,     //85
            0.55f, -0.5f, -0.90f, 0.39f, 0.26f, 0.12f,  1.0f, 0.75f,    //86
            0.58f, -0.5f, -0.90f, 0.39f, 0.26f, 0.12f,  1.0f, 0.0f,     //87


            //chair rung 2 front to back

           -0.58f, -0.4f, -0.10f, 0.39f, 0.26f, 0.12f,  0.0f, 0.25f,    //88
           -0.55f, -0.4f, -0.10f, 0.39f, 0.26f, 0.12f,  0.0f, 0.5f,     //89
           -0.55f, -0.5f, -0.10f, 0.39f, 0.26f, 0.12f,  0.0f, 0.75f,    //90
           -0.58f, -0.5f, -0.10f, 0.39f, 0.26f, 0.12f,  0.0f, 0.0f,     //91

           -0.58f, -0.4f, -0.90f, 0.39f, 0.26f, 0.12f,  1.0f, 0.25f,    //92
           -0.55f, -0.4f, -0.90f, 0.39f, 0.26f, 0.12f,  1.0f, 0.5f,     //93
           -0.55f, -0.5f, -0.90f, 0.39f, 0.26f, 0.12f,  1.0f, 0.75f,    //94
           -0.58f, -0.5f, -0.90f, 0.39f, 0.26f, 0.12f,  1.0f, 0.0f,     //95

           //chair rung across the front

           -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.03f,  0.39f, 0.26f, 0.12f,  0.0f, 0.0f, //96
            0.5f, -0.5f, -0.03f,  0.39f, 0.26f, 0.12f,  1.0f, 0.0f, //97
           -0.5f, -0.4f, -0.03f,  0.39f, 0.26f, 0.12f,  1.0f, 0.5f, //98
            0.5f, -0.4f, -0.03f,  0.39f, 0.26f, 0.12f,  0.0f, 0.5f, //99


           -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.06f,  0.39f, 0.26f, 0.12f,  0.0f, 0.0f, //100
            0.5f, -0.5f, -0.06f,  0.39f, 0.26f, 0.12f,  1.0f, 0.0f, //101
           -0.5f, -0.4f, -0.06f,  0.39f, 0.26f, 0.12f,  1.0f, 0.5f, //102
            0.5f, -0.4f, -0.06f,  0.39f, 0.26f, 0.12f,  0.0f, 0.5f, //103

            //chair rung across the back

           -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.85f,  0.39f, 0.26f, 0.12f,  0.0f, 0.0f, //104
            0.5f, -0.5f, -0.85f,  0.39f, 0.26f, 0.12f,  1.0f, 0.0f, //105
           -0.5f, -0.4f, -0.85f,  0.39f, 0.26f, 0.12f,  1.0f, 0.5f, //106
            0.5f, -0.4f, -0.85f,  0.39f, 0.26f, 0.12f,  0.0f, 0.5f, //107


           -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.88f,  0.39f, 0.26f, 0.12f,  0.0f, 0.0f, //108
            0.5f, -0.5f, -0.88f,  0.39f, 0.26f, 0.12f,  1.0f, 0.0f, //109
           -0.5f, -0.4f, -0.88f,  0.39f, 0.26f, 0.12f,  1.0f, 0.5f, //110
            0.5f, -0.4f, -0.88f,  0.39f, 0.26f, 0.12f,  0.0f, 0.5f, //111


            








    };




    //Index data to share position data
    GLuint indices[] = {

            //chair leg
            0, 1, 2,    //Triangle 1
            1, 3, 2,    //Triangle 2
            4, 5, 7,    //Triangle 2
            4, 6, 7,    //Triangle 4
            4, 0, 2,    //Triangle 5
            4, 6, 2,    //Triangle 6
            1, 6, 3,    //Triangle 7
            2, 3, 6,    //Triangle 8
            5, 1, 3,    //Triangle 9
            5, 3, 7,    //Triangle 10
            5, 4, 0,    //Triangle 11
            5, 1, 0,    //Triangle 12

            //chair leg 2

             8, 9,10,   //Triangle 13
             9,11,10,   //Triangle 14
            12,13,15,   //Triangle 15
            12,14,15,   //Triangle 16
            12, 8,10,   //Triangle 17
            12,14,10,   //Triangle 18
             9,14,11,   //Triangle 19
            10,11,14,   //Triangle 20
            13, 9,11,   //Triangle 21
            13,11,15,   //Triangle 22
            13,12,8,    //Triangle 23
            13,9,8,     //Triangle 24

            //chair leg 3
            16,17,18,   //Triangle 25
            17,19,18,   //Triangle 26
            20,21,23,   //Triangle 27
            20,22,23,   //Triangle 28
            20,16,18,   //Triangle 29
            20,22,18,   //Triangle 30
            18,19,23,   //Triangle 31
            18,19,22,   //Triangle 32
            21,17,19,   //Triangle 33
            21,19,23,   //Triangle 34
            21,20,16,   //Triangle 35
            21,17,16,   //Triangle 36


            //chair leg 4
            24,25,29,   //Triangle 37
            24,28,29,   //Triangle 38
            25,27,29,   //Triangle 39
            27,31,29,   //Triangle 40
            27,26,31,   //Triangle 41
            26,30,31,   //Triangle 42
            26,30,24,   //Triangle 43
            24,28,30,   //Triangle 44
            29,28,30,   //Triangle 45
            29,31,30,   //Triangle 46
            24,25,26,   //Triangle 47
            25,27,26,   //Triangle 48


            //seat  (fixed missing polygons)
            32,33,34,   //Triangle 49
            32,33,35,   //Triangle 50
            32,34,37,   //Triangle 51
            32,36,37,   //Triangle 52
            37,39,38,   //Triangle 53
            37,36,38,   //Triangle 54
            39,35,33,   //Triangle 55
            39,38,33,   //Triangle 56
            35,34,37,   //Triangle 57
            35,39,37,   //Triangle 58
            33,32,36,   //Triangle 59
            33,38,36,   //Triangle 60


            //BASE OF CHAIR  (fixed missing polygons)
            40,41,42,  //Triangle 61
            40,42,43,   //Triangle 62
            42,40,44,   //Triangle 63
            42,45,44,   //Triangle 64
            45,44,46,   //Triangle 65
            45,47,46,   //Triangle 66
            44,45,46,   //Triangle 67
            47,43,41,   //Triangle 68
            47,46,41,   //Triangle 69
            43,42,45,   //Triangle 70
            43,47,42,   //Triangle 71
            41,40,44,   //Triangle 72
            41,46,44,   //added triangle as missing in seat base

            //chair tower 1
            48,49,53,   //Triangle 73
            48,52,53,   //Triangle 74
            49,51,55,   //Triangle 75
            49,53,55,   //Triangle 76
            51,50,55,   //Triangle 77
            50,54,55,   //Triangle 78
            50,54,52,   //Triangle 79
            50,48,52,   //Triangle 80
            52,53,54,   //Triangle 81
            53,55,54,   //Triangle 82
            48,49,50,   //Triangle 83
            49,51,50,   //Triangle 84

            //chair tower 2
            56,57,61,   //Triangle 85
            56,60,61,   //Triangle 86
            57,59,63,   //Triangle 87
            57,61,63,   //Triangle 88
            59,58,63,   //Triangle 89
            58,62,63,   //Triangle 90
            58,62,60,   //Triangle 91
            58,56,60,   //Triangle 92
            60,61,62,   //Triangle 93
            61,63,62,   //Triangle 94
            56,57,58,   //Triangle 95
            57,59,58,   //Triangle 96

            //chair horiz back
            64,65,67,   //Triangle 97
            64,65,66,   //Triangle 98
            64,68,71,   //Triangle 99
            64,67,71,   //Triangle 100
            68,69,70,   //Triangle 101
            68,71,70,   //Triangle 102
            65,69,64,   //Triangle 103
            66,70,69,   //Triangle 104
            66,70,67,   //Triangle 105
            67,71,70,   //Triangle 106
            65,64,68,   //Triangle 107
            65,69,64,   //Triangle 108

            //chair horiz back lower
            72,73,75,   //Triangle 109
            73,74,75,   //Triangle 110
            72,76,79,   //Triangle 111
            79,75,72,   //Triangle 112
            79,76,77,   //Triangle 113
            79,78,77,   //Triangle 114
            74,78,77,   //Triangle 115
            73,74,77,   //Triangle 116
            75,79,78,   //Triangle 117
            75,74,78,   //Triangle 118
            72,73,77,   //Triangle 119
            72,76,77,   //Triangle 120

            //chair rung front to back
            81,80,83,   //Triangle 121
            81,82,83,   //Triangle 122
            80,83,87,   //Triangle 123
            80,84,87,   //Triangle 124
            84,87,86,   //Triangle 125
            84,85,86,   //Triangle 126
            86,85,81,   //Triangle 127
            81,82,86,   //Triangle 128
            82,83,87,   //Triangle 129
            83,82,86,   //Triangle 130
            81,80,84,   //Triangle 131
            80,81,85,   //Triangle 132

            //chair rung 2 front to back
            89,88,91,   //Triangle 133
            89,90,91,   //Triangle 134
            88,91,95,   //Triangle 135
            91,95,92,   //Triangle 136
            92,95,94,   //Triangle 137
            92,93,94,   //Triangle 138
            94,93,89,   //Triangle 139
            89,90,94,   //Triangle 140
            91,90,95,   //Triangle 141
            90,94,95,   //Triangle 142
            89,88,92,   //Triangle 143
            89,93,92,   //Triangle 144

            //chair rung 3 across the front
            99,97,96,       //Triangle 145
            96,98,99,       //Triangle 146
            97,101,103,     //Triangle 147
            97,99,103,      //Triangle 148
            101,100,102,    //Triangle 149
            101,103,102,    //Triangle 150
            102,98,96,      //Triangle 151
            102,100,96,     //Triangle 152
            102,103,99,     //Triangle 153
            99,98,102,      //Triangle 154
            96,97,101,      //Triangle 155
            97,96,100,      //Triangle 156

            //chair rung 4 across the back
            104,105,107,    //Triangle 157
            107,106,104,    //Triangle 158
            105,109,111,    //Triangle 159
            105,107,111,    //Triangle 160
            109,111,110,    //Triangle 161
            109,108,110,    //Triangle 162
            106,110,108,    //Triangle 163
            106,104,108,    //Triangle 164
            106,110,111,    //Triangle 165
            106,107,111,    //Triangle 166
            104,105,109,    //Triangle 167
            104,108,109,    //Triangle 168





    };

    //Generate buffer IDs
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO); // activate vertex array object before binding and setting any VBOs and Vertex Attribute Pointers

    //Activate VBO
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW); // copy vertices to VBO

    //Activate EBO
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW); // copy vertices to EBO

    //set attribute pointer 0 to hold position data
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0); //Enables vertex attribute

    //Set attribute pointer 1 to hold Normal data
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    //Set attribute pointer 2 to hold Texture coordinate data
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(6 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glBindVertexArray(0); // deactivates the VAO - good practice

}



//GENERATE AND LOAD TEXURE ... Note to self look into texture arrays
void UGenerateTexture(){
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    int width, height;

    unsigned char* image = SOIL_load_image("darkwood.jpg", &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGB);//loads texture file

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    SOIL_free_image_data(image);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0); //Unbind the texture
}
```

Comment: there are 3 options. **1.** render each object with separate `glDraw....`  call with correct texture binded.  **2.** add object/texture index  into VBO pass it to shaders and in fragment decide which texture to use along with binded each texture (multi texturing) to separate unit however this is a bad way as you limit number o fobjects by number of texture units **3.** use bind less texturing I never used this but it should work just like #2 except you do not bind any texture on CPU side instead you just pick the texel from correct texture based on the object ID in fragment

Comment: Unless you got too many objects I prefer #1 as you need to pass uniforms on per object to shaders anyway.

Comment: I will give option 1 a shot first. Thank you so much for the information.